# Randomly assign each of the coordinates [a,b] with each of the elements in a list

Tags: python

```
GRIDCOLS = 3;

GRIDROWS = 4 ;

gidder = 20;

gridxy = [];

for column in range (GRIDCOLS): 
..   yrow = column * 100+ 50 

..   for row in range (GRIDROWS): 

..     xcell = row * 100+50 

..     ycell = yrow + random.randint(-gidder, gidder) 

..     gridxy.append([xcell, ycell]) 

..     print (gridxy)
```

this would create something like this `[50, 58], [150, 56], [250, 39], [350, 52]`

```
sumlist = ['a','b','c','$','4','2','3']
```

and what i want to do is assigning each of the coordinates [a,b] with each of the elements within the sumlist randomly.

I'm not really sure how to approach this. Do i do something with the index? Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "assigning each of the coordinates [a,b] with each of the elements within the `sumlist` randomly"? What result are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of assignment do you need?

You can use [`zip([iterable, ...])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

> This function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

```
>>> zip(sumlist, gridxy)
[('a', [50, 58]), ('b', [150, 56]), ('c', [250, 39]), ('$', [350, 52])]
```

You can create a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict):

```
>>> dict(zip(sumlist, gridxy))
{'a': [50, 58], 'b': [150, 56], 'c': [250, 39], '$': [350, 52]}
```

If you need a ordered dictionary you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

> Return an instance of a dict subclass, supporting the usual dict methods.

Answer (score 0):

You must `random.shuffle` your data...

```
import random
sumlist = ['a','b','c','$','4','2','3']
random.shuffle(sumlist) # shuffles in place!
```

At this point you have a random permutation of your data, stored into `sumlist` and you can proceed with pairing the `sumlist` and the `gridxy` elements, usually using the `zip` builtin (that truncates the pairing at the shortest iterable's length) or [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) in the `itertools` module that allow you to use a default value as a fill-in.

```
# create a list of tuples
lot = [t for t in zip(sumlist,gridxy)]
# create a dict
d = {s:xy for s, xy in zip(sumlist,gridxy)}
```

Of course you can use `zip_longest` if you feel appropriate to use default values in your code.

Pay attention to the fact that `random.shuffle` operates in place (and returns `None`), so that if you want to access your data in the original order, then you want to save it somewhere before shuffling

```
...
original_list = sumlist[:]
random.shuffle(sumlist)
...
```